# If A is an unbounded set of real numbers, prove that there exists a sequence of elements in A without a convergent subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis

I have an idea that we will use sequential compactness to answer this question, but that is as far as I have struggled so far.

EDIT: Before I did not clearly define A as a set of real numbers.

Comment: What type of thing is $A$?  You've tagged this as real-analysis, so I'm led to expect it's a measurable function?  Is $A$ a set?  a metric space?  a Hilbert space?  a dual space?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the flaw in the post; I'm still fairly new to the site and should have been more thorough in my Question Header. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

If $A$ is unbounded, $A$ must not be totally bounded, so $A$ is not compact by Heine-Borel, $A$ is not sequentially compact by Bolzano-Weierstrass. Hence there exists a sequence in $A$ without a convergent subsequence.

Hard way:

Choose any $x \in X$. ($(X,d)$ is the space containing $A$) By unboundedness, for every $j \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $y_j \in A$ with $d(x,y_j) > j$. Can the sequence $(y_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ have a convergent subsequence?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an unbounded set. Then, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ choose $x_n \in A$ such that $|x_n| > n$. I encourage you to try to show that the sequence $(x_n)_n$ does not have a converging subsequence. Hint: Suppose that there is a converging subsequence of $(x_n)$, what would happen then?